# Correct way to pass function in reactjs with hooks

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

Hello I have a question about the correct way to pass a function to a children
Basically in my highest level component I have a theme:

```
export default function App() {
  const { theme, setTheme } = useAppTheme();

  useEffect(() => {});

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <div className="App">
        <Header />
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

this is my custom hook for get and set theme:

```
export default function useAppTheme(defaultTheme = lightTheme) {
  const [theme, _setTheme] = useState(getInitialTheme);

  function getInitialTheme() {
    const savedTheme = localStorage.getItem('theme');
    if (savedTheme === 'dark' || savedTheme === 'light') {
      return JSON.parse(savedTheme) === 'dark' ? darkTheme : defaultTheme;
    } else {
      return defaultTheme;
    }
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem('theme', JSON.stringify(theme.type));
  }, [theme]);

  return {
    theme,
    setTheme: ({ setTheme, ...theme }) => {
      if (theme.type === 'dark') {
        return _setTheme(darkTheme);
      } else {
        return _setTheme(lightTheme);
      }
    },
  };
}
```

and then in my component header I use useTheme from EMOTION Theme

```
const Header = () => {
  const Theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <Container theme={Theme}>
      <TopHeader theme={Theme} />
      <NavBar theme={Theme} />
    </Container>
  );
};
```

and then I have a component that is a child of my header where I need my setTheme function to change the theme:

```
const ItemsTop = props => {
  return (
    <WrapperTop
      justify={'space-between'}
      align={'center'}
      flexdirection={'row'}
    >
      <img src={LogoImg} />
      <SearchContainer>
        <div>
          <FontAwesomeIcon
            className="searchIcon"
            icon={faSearch}
            size="2x"
            fixedWidth
            color="white"
          />
        </div>
        <input placeholder="Pesquisar"></input>
      </SearchContainer>

      <AccessibilityTwo>
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          className="adjust"
          icon={faAdjust}
          size="1x"
          fixedWidth
          color="white"
        />
        <FontAwesomeIcon
          icon={faTextHeight}
          size="1x"
          fixedWidth
          color="white"
        />
      </AccessibilityTwo>
    </WrapperTop>
  );
};
```

So I would like to know what is the correct way to pass my setTheme function from my custom hook to the children of my component Header

Comment: Have you tried to pass as a prop?

Comment: @Victor Ferreira I didn't try because I don't know what the best way to do this is in my cmoponent son or in my header

Answer (score 1):

I don't know how you are using the `ItemsTop` component, but imagine you call it in the `Header`:

```
const Header = () => {
  const Theme = useTheme();
  return (
    <Container theme={Theme}>
       ...
      <ItemsTop setTheme={props.setTheme}/>
    </Container>
  );
};
```

The code above is passing the function `setTheme` to the props of `ItemsTop`, but for this function to be present in the `props` of `Header` you have to pass it like:

```
export default function App() {
  const { theme, setTheme } = useAppTheme();

  useEffect(() => {});

  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <GlobalStyle />
      <div className="App">
        <Header setTheme={setTheme} />
      </div>
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

Finally, you can use it in `ItemsTop` accessing props: `props.setTheme`